# Passing object between javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say you have an object formatted something like the following in one script (javascript)-

```
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyeColor:"blue"
};
```

Is there an intuitive way to "send" this object to another (javascript) script? Basically, i'm trying to communicate data within 2 scripts on a webpage and attempting to avoid having one big script, which would eliminate this problem.

I've already messed around with simply creating a div with a bunch of inner div's which hold the information from the object (All it's holding is text/numbers) but I feel like there has to be a better way of doing this in either javascript or jQuery.

Comment: So you pass the object? What is the problem? Can you show how you are passing it and it is not working?

Comment: If this is client-side, and this isn't enclosed in a block, it will default to being global, thus available in other client-side JS scripts.

Comment: @epa, how exactly? 2 different scripts- how do I communicate between them?

Comment: What do you mean by *"communicate between them"*? Show some code context and a proper explanation of exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Two scripts on the same page? You either pass it or you reference it.

Comment: @Alex I'm confused about your question. This variable from script #1 will be available in your other scripts served in the browser as well. You just need to reference it, i.e. `person`

Comment: @Abdul, yes it's client-side. Could you post an example of what you're saying?

Comment: Is it possible that you assigned something else to person?  Or you reference person before the script that declares/defines it? The scripts share the same namespace.

Comment: Exactly what bdkopen said- i'm working through HTML

Comment: You could use jQuery's `$(element).data()` to associate the object with an element. Or you could put it in `localStorage`.

Comment: Or you can assign it to a global variable. There are lots of ways to do it, you can choose.

Comment: @Barmar, that seems to be what I need. Ill try that real quick

Comment: @Alex How are you exactly "calling upon" the object in the second script, and what's the error?

Comment: Barmar's jQuery `data()` solution seems to have worked for me

Comment: @Barmar, is there anything else I must do? I have this- `$("#holder").data(person);` where I set the data and this-`console.log($("#holder").data());` when i'm trying to read in the other script. I don't know if this makes a difference, but i'm inserting these scripts in after the page has loaded. After I set the data to the object i'm able to run the "reading" code in console and it works fine but when it runs in my second script, I get "undefined"

Comment: You need to give a name to the data: `$("#holder").data("person-info", person)`. Then to retrieve it you use `$("#holder").data("person-info")`

Comment: It seems like you must not have read the documentation very carefully.

Comment: It works fine without giving the data a key. When I use the key-value method I get an undefined value. When I was doing it without the key-values, I was getting an arbitrary object (not the one i saved)

Comment: @Barmar, Like I said above, I can set some data in the first script then run `$("#holder").data()` directly in the console and that will return the object. The problem is that when I try that in my second script I'm getting either a blank object or undefined (see my last comment)

Comment: You're right, `.data()` allows providing multiple data values in a key-value object, I forgot about that. I'm not sure why it's not working in your script, unless something else in the script deletes the element and inserts a new one with the same ID. Can you post the code of the two scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript files are not nodes on a network or system components.  They do not "send" or "receive" anything.  They are just bits of text that don't do anything by themselves at all.

Rather, your *browser* loads Javascript files, interprets them, and executes them.  They are all loaded into a *single, common sandbox* and they all share the global namespace.  The idea that data is sent from one script to another is simply a misunderstanding of how this all works.  If you ask developers how to send data between scripts, they are going to have trouble answering, because the question is more or less gibberish.  You have to post your code and be specific about the problem you are having.

If you are receiving an error like "ReferenceError: X is not defined" it is probably because X does not exist in the scope of the function that is throwing the error.  For example, if you declared X with the `var` keyword within a function block and then attempted to access X from another function.  If you wish to access a local variable from another function, you will have to pass it as a function argument or parameter.

I can provide a much more precise answer if you post your code.